Uninstalling all python packages before making a conda environment
Not necessarily sure whether this is the right way to go about this but from what I understand (and I really don't understand this if I'm being honest) by making a conda environment and installing a specific python version and as well as my desired packages they will all be stored in one location and make everything a lot more organized which is something I really want.
My file organization is absolutely horrible and I kind of want to just restart and uninstall all python versions and packages on my computer and then make a conda environment which has everything. Is this the right way to go about this? And if so how can I ensure I'm doing it correctly.

please rephrase your question: "Is this the right way..." is not on topic for this site, as you can only expect to get opinionated answers. "How do I uninstall all python versions from my operating system?" is (probably) on topic. But then we are missing information about which OS you are running.
